# How to install Rails 2.3.2 and 2.3.4 simultaneously on Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, rubygems, ubuntu-9.04

I need to install Rails 2.3.2 and Rails 2.3.4 simultaneously on my Ubuntu 9.04 server.  How do I do this?

When I run:

```
sudo gem install rails
```

...it installs version 2.3.4.  Is there a single command I can use to also install 2.3.2 parallel to the default (latest) version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use the -v option to gem:

```
sudo gem install rails -v=2.3.2
```

you'll have to do a separate install for 2.3.4 though

Comment: Thx!  I guess I could have looked that up.... It actually installs the older versions for all the associated gems as well.  Awesome!

Comment: It installs the correct version of those gems because they are treated as hard dependencies required by the particular version of Rails.

Comment: You might want to consider freezing your gems to /vendor/rails too.

Answer (score 1):

once installed you can specify which version you want to use for a specific rail app by editing the environment.rb file

config/environment.rb

```
# Specifies gem version of Rails to use when vendor/rails is not present
RAILS_GEM_VERSION = '2.3.4' unless defined? RAILS_GEM_VERSION
```