# How can I switch between rails 3.2.13 and rails 4.0.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `ubuntu 12.04`. I have installed `ruby 1.9.3` and `rails 3.2.13`. When I check my version of rails using command `rails -v`, it shows `Rails 4.0`. How can I switch to `Rails 3.2.13`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637392/how-to-install-rails-2-3-2-and-2-3-4-simultaneously-on-ubuntu-9-04

Comment: I would suggest to use https://rvm.io/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have already installed rails and its current version is 4.0, so please do this
`gem install rails -v 3.2.13` and if you want  to remove 4.0 version please do gem uninstall rails, you will get the list of rails and then choose 4.0.0 version.

Simple If you want to switch rails then you can install multiple rails version by using
  `sudo gem install rails -v 3.2.x or gem install rails` or any version you want

If you want to switch ruby version use rvm and choose `rvm use 1.9.3 or rvm use 2.0.0`

Thanks

Comment: Note for anyone else that ends up here in the future; `gem install rails -v '~> 3'` is the best way to pull in 3.x and get the latest in that version series.

Answer (score 6):

`rails new appname` will use the latest version of rails. To use an earlier installed version, call:

```
rails _3.2.13_ new appname
```

You can then have both versions of rails installed and not have to deal with uninstalling rails which can be problematic.